# XNA: Regarding SpriteBatch.Draw()

Tags: xna, spritebatch

I was trying to develop a very simple ping pong game using XNA.

In my Draw() I am drawing the player paddles first then the ball as follows:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(myPlayer, myPlayer1Pos, null, Color.Aqua);
spriteBatch.Draw(myPlayer, myPlayer2Pos, null, Color.Aqua);
spriteBatch.Draw(myBall, myBallPos, Color.LawnGreen);
```

Now the problem is the ball is no longer displayed in the game window as shown below
[image]

If on the other hand I draw the ball before the player paddle

```
spriteBatch.Draw(myBall, myBallPos, Color.LawnGreen);
spriteBatch.Draw(myPlayer, myPlayer1Pos, Color.Aqua);
spriteBatch.Draw(myPlayer, myPlayer2Pos, Color.Aqua);
```

then the right hand side paddle is no longer visible as shown below:
[image]

Can anyone explain what is going wrong here?

edit: The complete Draw():

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
      GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

      // TODO: Add your drawing code here
      spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend);

      spriteBatch.Draw(myBall, myBallPos, null, Color.LawnGreen);

      spriteBatch.Draw(myPlayer, myPlayer1Pos, null, Color.Aqua);
      spriteBatch.Draw(myPlayer, myPlayer2Pos, null, Color.Aqua);

      spriteBatch.Draw(myBkgTexture, graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Bounds, Color.Blue);

      spriteBatch.End();

      base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

Comment: Can you post more info about the problem, please?

Comment: Hey thanks, but can you tell what additional information about problem you want because this is all which I am drawing inside the Draw().

Comment: Thats definitly a bit peculiar. What happens when you draw the ball with the same overloaded Draw as the paddles? (the nullable rectangle after the position)

Comment: There is no change. If I understand correctly null ensures that the sprite is drawn in entirely. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Dimensions: Player paddle is 14*60 and ball is 16*16

Comment: Nope, you're correct about that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433990.aspx Just wanted to check if spritebatch was overriding something. Let me try to repro on my vs. Are you doing anything else that could potentially effect this?

Comment: Gave it a shot with the same setup. 3 Vector2's, 2 Textures, and the 3 calls. Displayed correctly each time. Are these definitly being drawn after the background is drawn? Are you clearing the graphicsdevice each draw call? You're doing Spritebatch.Begin and End?

Comment: @MintyAnt OK, another strange behavior, have mentioned it as an edit.

Comment: and ya i am calling begin() and end() before draw()

Comment: Are you just making the Texture by your own, filling the pixel array, or loading images?

Comment: I am loading the images.

Comment: Just a little test, try to draw like in the second method you shown, but move myPlayer2Pos like 200 px to the left.

Comment: hmm same result :(

Comment: Please post your full Draw method, not just those 3 lines.

Comment: Why are you drawing the background after the paddles? In that order, the background *should* be drawin in front of everything. Try drawing the background first, then all the game objects

Comment: @Luis, have posted the complete Draw()

Comment: The default Begin() uses SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, hence if i try to draw the background first then nothing else gets displayed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first problem is that you're using `SpriteSortMode.BackToFront` which to put it simply, is not appropriate for this case because you're not even specifying the depth of your sprites. Just use the default mode instead which draws in the same order as your calls (just write `spriteBatch.Begin()` with no parameters). Also, it's strange that you're drawing the background after the other sprites. If it's the background it should come first otherwise it will occlude everything else.

Here's the corrected code, with some redundant parameters removed:

```cs
spriteBatch.Begin();
spriteBatch.Draw(myBkgTexture, graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Bounds, Color.Blue);
spriteBatch.Draw(myBall, myBallPos, Color.LawnGreen);
spriteBatch.Draw(myPlayer, myPlayer1Pos, Color.Aqua);
spriteBatch.Draw(myPlayer, myPlayer2Pos, Color.Aqua);
spriteBatch.End();
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks. 
The Begin() with SpriteSortMode.BackToFront was generated by the Wizard and I never went to change it. But as mentioned by you using the default Begin() solves the issue.
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be with spriteBatch.Begin() which the wizard had generated with SpriteSortMode.BackToFront.

Using the default Begin() solves the issue.